# VSCode open workspace folder hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am wondering if there is a way I could bind a keyboard shortcut to open the OS File Explorer at the root workspace directory.

Furthermore, I would also like to be able to open a specific folder, relative to my workspace path, with the press of a keyboard shortcut.

I have search through the settings file, and for extensions, but I didn't come up with anything yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be by using a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) and a [keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

---

**Workspace Folder**

To open the workspace using <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>, create a task:

*tasks.json*

```
{
    "label": "explore workspace",
    "type": "shell",
    "windows": {
        "command": "explorer ${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "osx": {
        "command": "open ${workspaceFolder}"
    }
}
```

Note the task label.  Ad a corresponding keybinding:

*keybindings.json*

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "explore workspace"
}
```

Note the `args` value matches the task's `label` value.

---

**Folder relative to workspace**

Assume you want to open `${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin`.  Add the task:

```
{
    "label": "explore bin",
    "type": "shell",
    "windows": {
        "command": "explorer ${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\.bin"
    },
    "osx": {
        "command": "open ${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin"
    }
}
```

and a corresponding keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "explore bin"
}
```

---

*Disclaimer*: Only tested on Windows

Comment: This works on linux too! (I just removed osx/windows dicts to put command on same level than type & label).